# str_replace; Replace all letters with a * Minus The First?

Tags: php

I am trying to replace all Letters of a given string with an asterisk, minus the first letter. I have tried this:

```
$AnswerArr = str_split($Answer);
$AnswerCount = count($Answer);
$Toreplace = $AnswerCount - 1;
$ReplaceAnswer = str_replace($AswerArr['0'], "*", $Answer, $Toreplace);
```

But this does not work, Do I have to use a regular expression?

Using the first answer provided :

```
Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/New/API/FormValidation.php on line 15

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/New/API/FormValidation.php on line 15

Warning: str_repeat() [function.str-repeat]: Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in /var/www/New/API/FormValidation.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$tmp = preg_replace('/(?!^)[\S \t]/', '*', $inputstr);
```

Comment: Perfect! All though, how does the regular expressions work? I have no idea on the usage of them or how to construct

Comment: (?!^) with check if its not the first character [\S \t] means any combination of characters or digits or white space or tabs.

Comment: for more imformation about regular expresions you can go through this http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ReplaceAnswer = substr($Answer, 0, 1) . str_repeat('*', strlen($Answer) - 1);
```

Comment: You would have to check that the answer is at least 1 character long or use `max(0, strlen($Answer) - 1)` instead. And can you post the exact code that you used?